# Minimal Ubuntu, LTS?

Tags: lts, ubuntu-minimal

According to wiki.ubuntu.com the LTS designation applies only to specific subsets of Ubuntu archive and the LTS may not apply to all flavours and remixes of Ubuntu.

Can anyone tell me if the new Minimal Ubuntu falls under the LTS designation?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Minimal
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Comment: For LTS or long-term-support means 5 years of support only for software found in 'main'.  All [official] flavors contain software from 'universe' where LTS means 3 years of support  (by default, but you should check for each package as some can have 2 years, some >3). My point is after installing the minimal Ubuntu, you're likely to install extra software, and the length of the support will vary on what software you add to your system, so it's not just the image you use that you need to take into account. (for info on repositories - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Comment: I have several times installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with "minimal installation" option. I understand that it will not install many apps like for example "thunderbird" "rhythm box" "Libre office" etc.. Except this everything is same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minimal Ubuntu** refers to small installation ISO's that do not contain the graphical installer nor the packages. Such images contain only the files needed for a basic install of the system. The bulk of the system is installed over the internet. These images are mostly intended for more automated deployment. As such, the final desktop you install with these images is identical to a regular Ubuntu 18.04 install, and thus is equally Long Term Supported.

You may be confused with the **Minimal Install** option on the regular installation ISO's, which is something else than Minimal Ubuntu. The Minimal Install involves an  option in the regular installation program to essentially only install the system and the browser. The user can then manually install other applications he/she needs. Also here, of course, the result is a fully LTS desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 brings a new **minimal install** installer option for a basic desktop environment with a web browser and core system utilities. Many official 18.04 desktop flavors are using this new feature too. The 18.04 minimal install option installs a true LTS operating system, the same as the regular 18.04 installer option does with the same period of long term support.